# OR operator in while loop doesn't exit

Tags: c, while-loop

```
do{
    printf("Monster name:%s\n",monsternames[globalvar.monstercatego][globalvar.monsternivel]);
    printf("Monster Life:%d\n",globalvar.monsterhp);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("----------------BattleGround--------------\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Player name:%s\n", nomeheroi);
    printf("Player life:%d\n", globalvar.playerhp);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("------------------Menu------------------\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("A - Attack\n");
    printf("D - Defend\n");
    scanf(" %c",&opcaobattle);
    switch(opcaobattle)
    {
        case 'a':
        danoPMonster();
        break;

        case 'd':

        break;
    }
  }while((globalvar.monsterhp >= 0) || (globalvar.playerhp >= 0));
```

My console shows:

```
Monster name:Rat
Monster Life:2
----------------------------------------
----------------BattleGround------------
----------------------------------------
Player name:Test
Player life:10
----------------------------------------
------------------Menu------------------
----------------------------------------
A - Attack
D - Defend

a

Monster name:Rat
Monster Life:-1
----------------------------------------
----------------BattleGround------------
----------------------------------------
Player name:Test
Player life:10
----------------------------------------
------------------Menu------------------
----------------------------------------
A - Attack
D - Defend
```

It clearly show that `globalvar.monsterhp < 0` and didn't leave the loop any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using `||` logical OR operator means is any one of the condition will be true then loop will continue. and Player life is `>0`, So it is not exiting loop

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you only want to iterate while both the monster *and* the player are alive. Your code iterates while at least one is alive. Change the condition from "or" to "and."

```
while((globalvar.monsterhp >= 0) || (globalvar.playerhp >= 0));
// to
while((globalvar.monsterhp >= 0) && (globalvar.playerhp >= 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'or' `||` condition means that the loop will not terminate until both `globalvar.monsterhp` is negative *and* `globalvar.playerhp` is negative; if either or both values are positive, the loop will continue.

If you want the loop to terminate when either value is negative, you need to use 'and' `&&` in the condition.